# QT Deploy: QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component

Tags: c++, qt, windows-10, mingw

I copied the depends dll files to my compile output folder by `windeployqt.exe`, and the `libgcc_s_seh-1.dll`, `libstdc++-6.dll`, `libwinpthread-1.dll`.

When running the exe file, it could not run correct.

I Then tried to run it in QT creator.
It shows:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component

qrc:/main.qml:3:1: ??�AQtQuick.Layouts????��??
```

My environment:
Windows10 x64, QT Creator 5, QT 6.1.3, MinGW 81_64

Could you please kindly point out my issue?